# Loan with floating interest

Tags: loans, interest-rate, compound-interest

I have taken a 7 years loan of 450 000 for a car in January 2017 with monthly payment of 7077.  The interest rate was 8.25% which means that the total repayment is 593878 after 7 years.  As from November 2017 till now, since the interest rate has changed, I have been paying 6972.69 par month. 
Can any one please tell me what is the new interest rate since November 2017 and also how much I left I need to repay.
I am at lost about how to calculate that with floating interest.

Comment: what currency is that?  and is this a homework question?

Comment: Are you sure the initial payment isn't 7070?

Comment: Calculating payments from total: `593878/7/12 = 7069.98`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the answer to this question:-

[Calculate mortgage rate with a different interest rate after certain years](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/96011/11768)

```
s = principal
r = monthly interest rate
n = number of months
d = monthly payment

s = 450000
r = 8.25/100/12
n = 7*12
```

Payment amount to pay off at 8.25% over 7 years ([ref. formula](http://financeformulas.net/Annuity_Payment_Formula.html))

```
d = r (1 + 1/((1 + r)^n - 1)) s = 7069.98
```

However, the interest rate changes after 10 months.

For calculations with rate changes calculate the principal remaining at the time the rate changes, then treat the next period as a fresh amortisation.

Calculating the principal remaining after 10 months, `x`, resetting the value of `s`

```
x = 10
s = (d + (1 + r)^x (r s - d))/r = 408984.76
```

Continuing with new figures.

```
n = 7*12 - x
d = 6972.69
```

Numerically solving [annuity equation](http://financeformulas.net/Present_Value_of_Annuity.html) `s = (d - d (1 + r)^-n)/r` for `r`

```
r = 0.00647044
```

The new interest rate is `12 r = 7.76452 %`